# how to use phone's home button functionality?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a music application and I want to implement an IconButton which when user press this button , it cause app to use android and ios home button.
for example you can handle platform backButton via WillPopScope ;
and my question is that there is anything that acts like platform's home button?
because in some of my page I don't want to close app and instead I want that App has functionality when user tap platform's home button , transfer the user into phone home page and app work in behind 
like any new musicplayers !!!

```dart
Center(
  child:IconButton(
    icon:Icon(Icons.people),
    onPressed:(){
         // the problem is here
          },
       ),
     )
```

Comment: I speak for Android, you can't do this, because when user press home button application automatically closed from the system. You can't block this feature

Comment: Thanks for answer.but I think I am not super clear in my question.I want homeButton functionality ، and I want implement it in my onPressed, exactly phone home button functionality, and I don't want block any feature.